# Is there an object model for automating migrations?

Tags: entity-framework-4

Using EF migrations I wish to automate running a migration against an environment. I know I can do this via powershell call to Update-Database, but is there a way of doing this via the framework without having to launch an external process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in your DbContext:

```
public static void SetInitializer()
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<DataContext, Configuration>());
}
```

Where Configuration is:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DataContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

You'll still need to release a Migration file for migrations that will make changes that will result in dataloss (unless you set AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed to true in the Configuration class - danger!) but you can make these files using the Add-Migration command in PMC.